# Simple python regex

Tags: python, regex, json, escaping

I have a text file and a I want to replace the following pattern:

```
\"
```

with:

```
"
```

The initial version of what I'm looking at looks like:

```
{"latestProfileVersion":51,
"scannerAccess":true,
"productRatings":"[{\"7H65018000\":{\"reviewCount\":0,\"avgRating\":0}}
```

So someone embedded a JSON string inside a JSON response.

This is what I have currently:

```
rawAuthResponseTextFile = open(rawAuthResponseFilename,'r')
formattedAuthResponse   = open('formattedAuthResponse.txt', 'w') 

try:
    stringVersionOfAuthResponse = rawAuthResponseTextFile.read().replace('\n','')
    cleanedStringVersionOfAuthResponse = re.sub(r'\"', '"', stringVersionOfAuthResponse)
    jsonVersionOfAuthResponse = json.dumps(cleanedStringVersionOfAuthResponse)
    formattedAuthResponse.write(jsonVersionOfAuthResponse)

finally:
    rawAuthResponseTextFile.close()
    formattedAuthResponse.close
```

Using http://pythex.org/ I have found that `r'\"'` should match *only* `\"`, but this is not the case when I look at the output which appears to be adding additional escape characters.

I know I am doing something wrong because I cannot get the quotes around the embedded string to look like the quotes in the regular JSON no matter how much I tweek it, escape characters or no.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\\"', '"', stringVersionOfAuthResponse)`

Comment: Are you missing a `}]"` in the end of your json?  For example: `...:0}}]"]`?

Comment: That does not work @AvinashRaj, see below, and there is a bunch more JSON after that I didn't include

Comment: Given this situation, I would do the following: (a) convert the JSON to a Python dictionary, (b) traverse the dictionary looking for stringified JSON, (c) additionally decode sringified JSON.

Comment: @ohhh you accepted the solution which suggest my first comment. Then why you added `That does not work` ?

Comment: Sorry I explained below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex

```
\\"
```

You need to escape `\` with `\`